# NGINX set header if request is not proxied to an upstream app

Tags: nginx

How do I set headers for static file requests that are not proxied to an upstream app?

My NGINX config:

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:///{{ puma_socket }} fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;

    root /app_current_path/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    }
}
```

How do I set headers for static (Javascript) files that exist in the **`/app_current_path/public`** directory, but not for requests served by the upstream app?